# SQLiteConstraintException not caught

Tags: java, android, exception, try-catch

What is the problem with this code? It doesn't catch the exception thrown by `insertChild()` method.

```
childDbOps.open();
try {
    childDbOps.insertChild(child);
} catch (SQLiteException exception) {
    Log.i("error la inserare child", "on the next line");
    exception.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    childDbOps.close();
}
```

The error is:

```
ERROR/Database(320): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: 
constraint failed at com.android.dataLayer.DbAdapter.insertChild(DbAdapter.java:169) 
  at com.android.activities.ChildInsertActivity.onClick(ChildInsertActivity.java:203) 
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2344)
```

It is android sqlite. The line is when the insert method is called.

Comment: Have you tried to just catch any exception using catch (Exception e){} ? It might give you a hint.

Comment: where does the exception indicate it was thrown from? make sure all your code is in a big generic try block & see what happens. which API is this - android sqlite?

Comment: ERROR/Database(320): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed at com.android.dataLayer.DbAdapter.insertChild(DbAdapter.java:169) at com.android.activities.ChildInsertActivity.onClick(ChildInsertActivity.java:203) at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2344)

yes, it is android sqlite. the line is when the insert method is called

Comment: you should mark http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421577/try-catch-problem/4900738#4900738 as correct answer :-)

Answer (score 46):

The SQLiteDatabase.insert() method is used in the cases where you want to handle database writes without unwinding the stack if a write fails. If you want to catch exceptions when inserting into the database, use the [SQLite.insertOrThrow()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertOrThrow(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) method. It will throw an exception which you can then catch and handle.

Comment: This is the answer. What was actually being reported wasn't the lack of catching a thrown error. The error wasn't actually being thrown. It was, however, being printed out to the logs. However, using insertOrThrow(), the exception will be thrown -- and then it can be caught. That's useful for eating known issues, such as the OPs constraint exception.

Answer (score 3):

You're catching only exceptions of type `SQLiteException`. If the `insertChild` method throws any other exception, it won't be caught.

```
try {
   childDbOps.insertChild(child);
}
catch(SQLiteException exception) {
  Log.i("error la inserare child", "on the next line");
  exception.printStackTrace();
}
catch(AnotherException exception) {
  //handle it
}
//Catch them all here
catch(Exception exception) {
  //handle it: must handle it, don't just swallow it.
}
finally {
  childDbOps.close();
}
```

Comment: I also tried with Exception which I know that is the superclass of all the exceptions and still doesnt work

Comment: @bogdan Are you sure there is an exception - what is the exception thrown? Is it thrown by `childDbOps.open();`, which is outside try block?

Comment: SQLiteConstraintException and is because I test what happens with my application when I enter again data with same primary key and I want to handle this. The insert method is my problem

Comment: But I dont know why It is not caught

Comment: [SQLiteConstraintException inherits SQLiteException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteConstraintException.html) - it should be caught; insert a `catch(SQLiteConstraintException sqlEx){}` as the first catch block to confirm.

Comment: still doesn't work

this is a part of the exception log and that is line 203 ->
08-06 07:21:16.148: ERROR/Database(320): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed

at com.android.dataLayer.DbAdapter.insertChild(DbAdapter.java:169)
at com.android.activities.ChildInsertActivity.onClick(ChildInsertActivity.java:203)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2344)

Comment: Check that answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421577/try-catch-problem/4900738#4900738 is the correct one, insert() doesn't throw exceptions, insertOrThrow() does it

Answer (score 0):

@bogdan is there any other place u are calling insertChild(child); other than this place. did  you put a trace in try block to know whether it comes to this block and print the trace like below.

> try    {          Log.i("comes
>   here");
>   childDbOps.insertChild(child);      }

let me know.

Comment: I put the log it enters right there. thats the only place I call the method

Comment: @bogdan thanks for the reply.from the trace i can see that  android.view.View.performClick  method handles the exception (means it has the catch block) , before it comes to your catch

Comment: hello, I solved my issue but without using the try catch. I make another query into the database to check if that primary key exists and that's it. I wasn't able to solve it in this form