# Why does my exception handler not trap Android SQLite insert error?

Tags: android, sqlite, exception

I'm using SQLite for the first time, and am trying to learn its exception handling, so I'm forcing an insert error in my test app.  The exception occurs and I see it written to the Eclipse LogCat output window. However it doesn't get caught in the code.  I've seen other questions here about being sure to use the correct exception type, and think I've got that right. Any idea what I'm missing?

In the following statement, which is in my main activity, `myTable` is a class which extends my own `AbstractDbAdapter` (which has a class `DatabaseHelper` that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`).

```
try {
    myTable.create("dupkey");
}
catch (android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "SQLiteConstraintException:" + e.getMessage());
}
catch (android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "SQLiteException:" + e.getMessage());
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Exception:" + e.getMessage());
}
```

Sample stack trace:

```
Error inserting id="dupkey" last_seen_ts=1360624732 first_seen_ts=1360624732 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:61)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1582)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1426)
  at com.myCompany.testApp.myTable_DbAdapter.create(myTable_DbAdapter.java:51)
```

The `myTable` and `AbstractDbAdapter` classes:

```
public class myTable_DbAdapter extends AbstractDbAdapter {

    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "myTable";

    // column names -- keys for ContentValues()
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_FIRST_SEEN = "first_seen_ts";
    public static final String KEY_LAST_SEEN = "last_seen_ts";

    public myTable_DbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx);
    }

    public long create(String id) {
        long firstSeen = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;  // SQLite timestamps are in seconds

        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_ID, id);
        args.put(KEY_FIRST_SEEN, firstSeen);
        args.put(KEY_LAST_SEEN, firstSeen);  // defaults to firstSeen for a new entry

        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, args);
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractDbAdapter {

    protected static final String TAG = "AbstractDbAdapter";

    protected DatabaseHelper mDbHelper = null;
    protected SQLiteDatabase mDb = null;

    protected static final String TABLE_CREATE_MYTABLE =
        "create table myTable (" +
        "  id text primary key not null" +
        ", first_seen_ts integer not null" +
        ", last_seen_ts integer not null" +
        ");";

    protected static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDB";
    protected static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    protected final Context mCtx;

    protected static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // Note: SQLite requires one execSQL per table
            db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE_MYTABLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + ", which destroys existing data.");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myTable");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public AbstractDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    public AbstractDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        if (mDb != null) {
            mDb.close();
            mDb = null;
        }
        if (mDbHelper != null) {
            mDbHelper.close();
            mDbHelper = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499201/sqliteconstraintexception-error-code-19-constraint-failed

Comment: Please post the code for `myTable_DbAdapter.create()` and indicate where line 51 is. Also, what class and method contains the code that you gave?

Comment: @Code-Guru: I've added the myTable class, line 51 is the create() method (it won't line up exactly to the stack trace because I removed some things to simplify it for this question).

Comment: @Alan Then you likely removed something that can help us answer your question. Please provide the full stack trace.

Comment: @Code-Guru: I removed a couple of methods from the myTable class code that are not used in this example, the stack trace was copied from the LogCat window.

Comment: @Alan If that is the full stack trace, then the code which contains your try...catch isn't even executed. Try arranging your code so that it actually executes.

Comment: What class and method contains the try...catch?

Comment: @Code-Guru: this code is all executed from my main activity.  I copied only the lines from the stack trace starting with the call to the create() method.  I was trying to be brief, understanding that I was leaving some things out.  Sorry if I've made it more difficult that way.

Comment: @Alan Can you please post more of the stack trace? In particular, I want to see the function that *calls* `create()`. You should post at least enough to show that the code you think should execute is actually executing.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I found the answer here: [SQLiteConstraintException not caught](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421577/try-catch-problem/4900738#4900738)

The SQLiteDatabase.insert() method doesn't throw an exception.  d'oh!

For other SQLite newbies like me, if you want to catch exceptions when inserting into the database, use the SQLite.insertOrThrow() method. It will throw an exception which you can then catch and handle.

Comment: Confirmed: by changing the myTable_DbAdapter class to use insertOrThrow(), I now get trappable errors in my test app and see only one line in the LogCat output "SQLiteConstraintException:error code 19: constraint failed" instead of a full stack trace.

Comment: Don't forget to add following code right after opening database in your Android app:

db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON");
This turns on support for foreign keys, which is necessary for ON DELETE CASCADE to work properly.

Comment: I am using sqlite in react-native(https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage). How can i handle the same? I am not able to find similar method

Comment: @SureshPrajapati good question, let me know if you find an answer!

Answer (score 1):

While not 100% related to the question, I ran into a similar problem using Room and Google returned this question for my search.  In the case of Room, there doesn’t appear to be a catchable exception thrown and insertOrThrow() does not exist.  In reviewing https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/OnConflictStrategy#ABORT:kotlin.Int, many of the options are depreciated, but I went with OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE here since this will return -1 if there is a problem.

Cheers.